# What does Heart of the Wild actually do for Boomkins?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As a Balance Druid, the level 90 talent Heart of the Wild tooltip says the following:

[image: When activated, dramatically improves the Druid's ability to tank, deal melee damage, and heal]

That's pretty ambiguous, especially considering I'm using the advanced tooltips for all my other abilities.

When I activate the skill, I see a buff that says "Healing ability and effectiveness in Cat Form and Bear Form increased."  Except, I'm Balance so I'm not quite sure how that helps.  The only visible effect I noticed was that my Healing Touch mana cost was reduced to 0.

I tried looking up the skill on wowhead and found three different versions, which still leaves it a little ambiguous as to the exact effect of the talent.

What benefit does Heart of the Wild grant a Balance Druid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heart of the Wild does the following for Balance druids:

- All your healing spells do 50% more healing and cost no mana.
- In cat form you gain 100% more agility.
- In bear form you gain 50% more agility and 100% more armor.

You can see the healing changes in the [spell description on Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=108291) (effects #1 and #2), the other effects are not directly visible. I used the spell and compared the values for cat and bear forms myself.

Comment: This ability is an "OH ####" button. If you suddenly lose a tank or healer, you can step into that role for a short time while they get a battle rez.